# Stack tbody at the top

Tags: css, css-tables

I have a table with a fixed height and a variable number of tbody elements.

```
table {
  border:1px solid black;
  height:300px;
}
```

By default the page increases the height of the first tbody to fill the total height of the table (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hvdcz8qr/). How can I have all the tbody elements stacked at the top of the table, and keep the extra height below the tbody elements?

Using elements other than table and tbody is not an option in my case.

[Update] I have added a second column to my example: http://jsfiddle.net/hvdcz8qr/10/

Comment: You could add another tbody with a 100% height td. Chrome devtools uses that on the resources tab.

Comment: @Rudie could you please show it on my demo? I already tried that and it didn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/hvdcz8qr/1/

Comment: Probably you don't mean something like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexChariz/hvdcz8qr/2/)

Comment: set `tbody` to `display:block` http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/hvdcz8qr/3/

Comment: Indeed... Doesn't work. With tbodies: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/hvdcz8qr/4/ Without tbodies: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/hvdcz8qr/5/ Devtools doesn't have tbodies =) Sorry

Comment: This is the problem with tables. The browser calculates dimensions according to insane algorithms. They don't do what you want, they do whatever they want.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/hvdcz8qr/6/ with `width:100%`

Comment: @AlexChar right, I still need the tbody to take the whole table width.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `display` of the `tbody` to `block`

```
table tbody { 
    display: block
}
```

## Edit

Inorder to make the td use all the space:

```
table tbody tr { 
    display: flex;   
}

td {
    border:1px solid red;
    display: block;    
    width: 100%;
}
```

[New JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hvdcz8qr/9/)

Comment: So now the issue is that the tbody doesn't take the whole table width anymore

Comment: The tbody IS taking all the space, the border is of the 'td'

Comment: thx for the updated answer, unfortunately I am in an older environment that does not support display flex (that also explains why tables are used for layout).

Answer (score 0):

After your comment in my suggestion try this:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 300px;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
tbody {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>First tbody
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>second tbody
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>third tbody
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

set `width: 100%` and `display: inherit` to take the whole table width.

Comment: This looked promising, unfortunately when I add more than one td in each row the columns are not aligned anymore.